# Getting an error (ReferenceError: steamMSG is not defined) even though I assign it a value

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am getting this error, "ReferenceError: steamMSG is not defined," even though I am assigning a value to steamMSG. I am really confused because when I log it in the console it works and show that it has a value.

Code:

```
if (command === "hex.steam") {
        var url = 'https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/ResolveVanityURL/v1/?key='+steamKey+'&format=json&vanityurl='+arguements;
        request(url, function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                var data = JSON.parse(body);
            } else {
                console.log("Got an error: ", error, ", status code: ", data.statusCode);
            }
            var steamMSG = data.response.steamid;
            console.log(steamMSG);
        });
        bot.sendMessage({
            to: channelID,
            message: steamMSG
        });
    }
```

The error is on this line:

```
message: steamMSG
```

Answer (score 0):

that's because the line `var steamMSG = data.response.steamid;` is in an asynchronous function, `bot.sendMessage()` is being called before it is defined.

easiest solution would be to stick `bot.sendMessage()` inside the function:

```
request(url, function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                var data = JSON.parse(body);
            } else {
                console.log("Got an error: ", error, ", status code: ", data.statusCode);
            }
            var steamMSG = data.response.steamid;
            console.log(steamMSG);

            bot.sendMessage({
            to: channelID,
            message: steamMSG
        });
});
```

the ideal solution would be to use promises.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your bot.sendMessage call in the callback of request.

Since "request" takes time to make its request, it has a callback for when it's done. This means bot.sendMessage is actually called before the request is done so steamMSG hasn't been defined yet.